# sql subqueries explained

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, subquery

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM (
     SELECT *
     FROM tutorial.sf_crime_incidents_2014_01
     WHERE day_of_week = 'Friday'
     ) sub
WHERE sub.resolution = 'NONE'
```

This subquery is not mine, it is from a tutorial website. I just want to clear the idea of the subquery, so first, the inner query is done and then the answer becomes in the alias name `<code>sub</code>`. Then the outer query takes the answer and selects all columns matching this answer with a where condition.Is this how it works?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conceptually**, this is how it works.

However, you need to be aware that you can not use subqueries to *force* the RDBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL or any other) to perform the operations in the *order* you described. The RDBMS will chose itself how it will execute the query through what is called a query plan.

For example, the following query expresses exactly the same as your query :

```
SELECT *
FROM tutorial.sf_crime_incidents_2014_01
WHERE day_of_week = 'Friday' AND sub.resolution = 'NONE';
```

And the optimizer is typically able to determine that your query can be simplified (I guess you'll agree that the above query is simpler than yours).

Note that it is more readable to pad the subqueries to distinguish easily what is the subquery and what is the main query :

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM tutorial.sf_crime_incidents_2014_01
  WHERE day_of_week = 'Friday'
) AS sub
WHERE sub.resolution = 'NONE';
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It will work if *sub.resolution* column exists in *tutorial.sf_crime_incidents_2014_01*  table